# how to open hyperlink in new tab dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to write code to open hyperlink in a new tab what is the property to open in new tab . if i add target = _blank its giving error

```
  firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "~/TargetReportsDetails.aspx?cat=" + categoryname + "&LinkSubmtdDate=" + lnksubsndt + " &LinkSubmittedBy=" + LinkSubmittdBy + " ", Text = firstCell.Text});
```

Answer (score -1):

To open a page in new tab from the hyperlink we can use `Target="_blank"`  in C#.

```
  firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "~/TargetReportsDetails.aspx?cat=" + categoryname + "&LinkSubmtdDate=" + lnksubsndt + " &LinkSubmittedBy=" + LinkSubmittdBy + " ", Text = firstCell.Text,Target="_blank"});
```

Comment: You should delete this post as your post  lacks quality if this is a question then re-edit above one.